# How to inherit narrowed type from function argument?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have a function that accepts as an argument another function. The argument is an union type of functions that also may have or may have not arguments.

```
type innerFn = () => void | (arg: string) => void | (arg: number) => void | (arg: {}) => void

function mainFn (innerFn: InnerFnType) {
   function run(arg?: *any*) {
      innerFn()
   }
   return run
}
```

I want to know if the **run** argument can be inherited based on the function that is passed to mainFn.

The use case is:

```
const concreteInnerFn: InnerFnType = (arg: string) {
     do something
}

const run = mainFn(concreteInnerFn)

run("hello")  // OK
run(25) // ERROR
run({hello: true}) // ERROR
```

ie if I use `(arg: string) => void` as the innerFn, when I try to use `run()` it should ask for an argument of type string.

Hope its clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it:

```js
type InnerFn =
  | (() => void)
  | ((arg: string) => void)
  | ((arg: number) => void)
  | ((arg: Record<string, unknown>) => void)

const main = <
  Params extends Parameters<InnerFn>,
  >(fn: (...params: Params) => void) =>
  (...args: Params) => fn(...args)

/**
 * Ok
 */
const result0 = main(() => { }) // ok
result0() // ok
const result1 = main((a: string) => { })// ok
result1('hello') // ok
const result2 = main((a: number) => { }) // ok
result2(42) // ok
const result3 = main((a: { age: number }) => { }) // ok
result3({ age: 42 })

/**
 * Errors
 */
const result4 = main((a: Promise<number>) => { }) // expected error
const result5 = main((a: number[]) => { }) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdnCAnAYnKBeAsAKClAHygApiBKTAPigDcB7ASwBMzd8jSBDJAcwC4oAZ2BIGcHhQzV6zVnkIli3flDgBXALYAjZJOmMWbBV14CAShADGdJEwA8w0eIA0UNXADWcOgHc4lPVoDOVxrOGEoDU4xTCg7IwAFbk4NQSgIAA9gCDgmNKSkFIhspEE7eERUf2cjSmIAMzgBYgA6NrBk1IEClMFAmRYqI1a25UFuzr6qKEaRlrGQnAB6ACoVthWoAHkPDaXQunDgKCQIQTUAG2AABliosVJAgG8oAF8KJaWoOl2cU-OrtdyFBPt9fmEIv9LsAAIx3aJwLgCRxiCTTF7vUE-XBQq4w4gAcgAFhALhc6ASPl9sTgIcdccAAEzwh5KATqbS6dFvKlgnFnaGM4gAFkZvJpdJOAquAGYWYi2VAXpweBB2ZodEgedz3iDqb8GTLiMrVQJRTzcLhVus8JsAKJIJA2QR7A5HKUA4DC+VIqAJJ0aBiCCB2DmagI63mZSCWbJMdKOmxuyHS4AAVh9irDyAA2gBdZ7a0HRqxxhNOpBAA)

**Explanation**

Please dont use `{}` as a type because it is very general type. Everything is an object in javascript and typescript. Hence `{}` can't be used as a constraint. It is better to use `Record<string, unknown>` for such purpose.

[`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) - returns a tuple of all arguments of passed function.

P.S. I hope you don't mind that I have used arrow function instead of `function`. I'm not saying it is better, it just the matter of a style.